# Conditional Formatting min value greater than 0

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Picture Of Issue]

I was able to use conditional formatting to find max value for each column.

When I try to find the minimum value for each column it is only highlighting some of the columns due to them containing zeroes.

I need to conditionally format the minimum value greater than 0 per column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try a formula of the kind:

```
=A1=ArrayFormula(min(if(A:A<>0,A:A)))
```